# How to return a value (number) if pandas contains condition is true?

Tags: python, pandas, contains

How can I individually return a value if the contains condition is true?

```
searchfor = ['dormant', 'open']]
flag_one = []
flag_one = data['Status'].str.contains('|'.join(searchfor), na=False)
```

Right now it returns a "True" if found or "False" if not found. How can I assign a (numerical) value to "True" and "False"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `map`

```
data['Status'].str.contains('|'.join(searchfor), na=False).map({True:111,False:222})
```

Comment: Sick! Thats what I want. Thank you so much.

Comment: @JohnDole yw :-)

Comment: Strange behaviour for invert operator: ~data['Status'].str.contains('|'.join(searchfor), na=False).map({True:1,False:0}) returns -1 and -2.. :D

Comment: (~data['Status'].str.contains('|'.join(searchfor), na=False)).map({True:1,False:0}),adding ()c@JohnDole

Answer (score 0):

I think this is want you want

```
if data['Status'].str.contains('|'.join(searchfor), na=False):
   flag_one = 1.0
else:
   flag_one = -1.0
```

Comment: what does this return if the condition is ``True``?

Comment: ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 47, placement implies 1

Answer (score 0):

Just re-assign `flag_one` after evaluating your condition:

```
if flag_one:
    flag_one = 3 # or any value you want for True
else:
    flag_one = 34 # or any value you want for False
```

Or you can go into the sources of `contains` function and change it but I woudn't recommend it.

Comment: Okay. Thank you! I thought there is a smarter way

Answer (score 0):

Use `numpy.where`:

```
searchfor = ['dormant', 'open']
x = 10
y = 20
data['new_column'] = numpy.where(data['Status'].isin(searchfor),x,y)
```

`new_column` will contain 10 when dormant or open is found in status, otherwise it'll contain 20.